# Update a specific field in a croncrete JSON object inside an JSON array (Mongoose)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to update a specific field in a concrete JSON object inside an JSON array with mongoose.
My MongoDB contains:

```
db.users.find({username:"xxx"})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56cb877e73da764818ec5ded"),..., "githubtoken" : [ { "token" : "9e37axxx", "username" : "xxx", "_id" : ObjectId("572a7cfafe95dec51d9cbf2d") }, { "token" : "4529yyy", "username" : "yyy", "_id" : ObjectId("572a7d3cfe95dec51d9cbf2e") } ] }
```

And I want to get the JSON object that matches with `"username" : "yyy"`and `"user._id" = "56cb877e73da764818ec5ded"` and change its token to `"token" : "4529zzz"` with mongoose, like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56cb877e73da764818ec5ded"),..., "githubtoken" : [ { "token" : "9e37axxx", "username" : "xxx", "_id" : ObjectId("572a7cfafe95dec51d9cbf2d") }, { "token" : "4529zzz", "username" : "yyy", "_id" : ObjectId("572a7d3cfe95dec51d9cbf2e") } ] }
```

The schema of db is:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    username  : { type: String, required: true },
    ...

    githubtoken: [ { username: {type: String, required: false },
        token: {type: String, required: false}  }]

});
```

And update method:

```
    userSchema.statics.updateuser = function updateuser (query, update, options) {
        var promise = new Hope.Promise();
        this.findAndUpdate(query, update, options,function(error, user) {
            if (error) {
                return promise.done(error, null);
            }else {
                return promise.done(null, user);
            }
        });
        return promise;
    };
```

And in my service with express.js:

```
query =  {$and: [{_id: userid}, {githubtoken: {username:username, token:oldToken}} ]};
        update = {$set : {githubtoken:{username:username, token:token}}};

    options = { new: true};


    User.updateuser(query,update,options).then(function (error,user){
        if(error){
            return promise.done(error,null);
        }else{

}});
```

But it doesn't work, because remove all array of githubtokens and push only the new githubtoken, like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56cb877e73da764818ec5ded"),..., "githubtoken" : { "token" : "4529zzz", "username" : "yyy", "_id" : ObjectId("572a7d3cfe95dec51d9cbf2e") }  }
```

Any idea?
Thank you very much :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24166615/update-an-item-in-an-array-that-is-in-an-array):

```
query = {"githubtoken" :{$elemMatch: {"username": username}}};


            update = {$set : {
                "githubtoken.$.username": username,
                "githubtoken.$.token": token
            }};
```

Thanks for the help :D

Comment: Yeah, `$elemMatch` was gonna be my next suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the query like this:

```js
var query = {
    {
        _id: new ObjectId(userid),
        'githubtoken.username': username,
        'githubtoken.token': oldToken
    }
};
```

And update like this:

```js
var update = {
    $set: {
        'githubtoken.$.username': username,
        'githubtoken.$.token': token
    }
};
```

Comment: Mongoose return me error: The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query.Unexpanded update: githubtoken.$.token.

Comment: It seems that for some of the userId, username and oldToken parameters in the query there is not a match. That makes the update to fail. If you set the `upsert` parameter to `true` then if there is not a match a new document will be created.

Comment: This query doesn't work, and I launch the query only with _id and it is match, the problem is $set.

Comment: Although work, the result would be the same as in my question, because the find returns a user and set $ crushes me array and make a push

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$` - positional operator for the update:

```
db.collection('users').update({
    "_id": ObjectId("56cb877e73da764818ec5ded"),
    "githubtoken.username": "xxx"
}, {
    $set: {
        "githubtoken.$.username": username,
        "githubtoken.$.token": token
    }
});
```

And this should do the trick. More details on usage of `$ - positional operator` https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/

Comment: Mongoose return me error: The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query.Unexpanded update: githubtoken.$.token.